# Permissão do android ao usar o CameraRoll para salvar foto na galeria usando React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-camera

Estou criando um aplicativo de wallpaper, porém a parte mais importe que é o botão de download não consigo fazer funcionar, estou usando o TouchableOpacity e dentro crio a função

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={
    async () => {
        try {
            const granted = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

            if (Platform.OS === "android" && granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(item);
                alert('foto salva')
            } else {
                console.log("Permissao de camera negada.");
                alert('permissão negada')
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }

}

} style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Download</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

esse item passado como parâmetro é o objeto da foto em si, quando clico no botão download ele cai no log de permissão negada, se alguém souber como resolver ou tiver alguma implementação para salvar foto na galeria agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Com apenas essa linha de código fica difícil ajudar, minha dica é você usar o [@react-native-community/cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll#save), não use o CameraRoll do React Native, ele está deprecated, ([você pode ver isso aqui](https://reactnative.dev/docs/cameraroll.html))

Lembre-se que antes de implementar o uso no seu código, você deve configurar a permissão nos arquivos, ...MainApplication.java, ...settings.gradle, ...build.gradle, ...Androidmanifest.xml, [você pode ver isso aqui](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll#android).

Deixe-me saber se eu lhe ajudei.